# Why is argv[1][0] not '?' for 'a.out ?' executed in a bash shell

Tags: c, bash, macos, shell

Why does the *?* below not show the help?  In other words, why is `argv[1][0]` not '?' when "a.out ?" is entered?

### File *pricePerGrmThc-v0.c*

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
**printf("<%c>\n", argv[1][0]);**
    if(argc == 1 || argv[1][0] == '?' || argv[1][0] == 'h' || argv[1][0] == 'H'){
        printf("Usage:  %s <THC %-age> <GMs> <$s> [<TCH %-age> <GMs> <$s> [<TCH %-age> <GMs> <$s> ...\n", argv[0]);
        return(1);
    }
    if(argc%3 != 1){
        printf("must input 3n vars\n");
        return(2);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < argc/3; i++){
        printf("%2.2f $/grOfThc\n", atof(argv[i * 3 + 3])  / (atof(argv[i * 3 + 2])  * atof(argv[i * 3 + 1])));
    }
    return(0);
}
```

### Execution 1

```
./a.out h
```

#### Output

```
<h>
Usage:  ./a.out <THC 0x0p+0ge> <GMs> <$s> [<TCH 0x0p+0ge> <GMs> <$s> [<TCH 0x0p+0ge> <GMs> <$s> ...
```

### Execution 2

```
./a.out ?
```

#### Output

```
<1>**
must input 3n vars
```

### Execution 3

```
./a.out ?est
```

#### Output

```
<?>
Usage:  ./a.out <THC 0x0p+0ge> <GMs> <$s> [<TCH 0x0p+0ge> <GMs> <$s> [<TCH 0x0p+0ge> <GMs> <$s> ...
```

Comment: What's your hope with `**printf("<%c>\n", argv[1][0]);**`? Remove the `**`

Comment: I think it's because `?` means something to the shell.

Comment: because the '?' is eaten by the shell. It means "file name consisting of just one character". Try `a.out "?"`

Comment: On top of the other points, why are you ignoring the compile warning telling you that you're doing something wrong later on? (Not escaping `'%'`)

Comment: thanks for the nits (fixed those) and the real ans (shell--obvious in hindsight)

Comment: Warnings are not "nits", they are important and serious hints that you have an error in your code. The compiler is just nice to you to let you shoot into your own foot. Only if it cannot continue in a meaningful way, it generates errors. Mostly.

Comment: The code does not compile: `"In function ‘main’: ... error: invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) **printf("<%c>\n", argv[1][0]);**"`. One way to draw attention to a particular line of code is (normal) code comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your shell replaces `?` with a list of the file names in the current directory that are one-character long.

```
$ ls -1 
a
b
c
def

$ ls -1 ?
a
b
c

$ echo ?
a b c

$ echo ?ef
def
```

You'll need to use some form of escaping or quoting.

```
$ echo \?
?

$ echo '?'
?
```

Answer (score 0):

`?` as a command line argument can be expanded if there are files in the current directory with a name consisting of a single character.

Note also that `%-age` should be written `%%-age` or perhaps `percentage` to avoid both the compiler warning and the undefined behavior at run time.

`%-a` expects a `double` argument (which is not provided) and converts it to hex-float format left aligned on its own width, as shown in the output: `0x0p+0`